# How to search for text in file and display lines

Tags: shell, command-line, command

I'm currently trying to search several .sql files that I have for certain text.  All of the .sql files are in the same folder.  Here's the command I'm using:

```
grep 'text to search for'
```

However, that isn't displaying the lines that contain the text I'm searching for.  Is there a way to display those lines and print them to a new text file?

Comment: There's simply not enough information here at all to provide a suggestion. You'll need to share exactly what you're searching for, and an example of what the inside of the `.sql` file looks like, especially a line that you are trying to match.

Comment: should be unix & linux stackexchange site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass an file or file pattern argument, like:

```
grep 'text to search for' *.sql
```